# Why does a scope service keep giving me new instances?

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

In Program.cs I have:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SessionData>();
```

And here is SessionData.cs

```
   public class SessionData
    {
        public bool ShowPhoneConfirmationBanner { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; } = _id++;

        private static int _id = 0;
    }
```

And finally this is in MainLayout.razor

```
[Inject]
private SessionData SessionData { get; set; } = default!;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
     bool show = SessionData.ShowPhoneConfirmationBanner 
     // do stuff ...
```

I watch this with the debugger and `OnInitializedAsync()` is called twice when first displaying Index.razor - and it's a different SessionData object each time.
I then go to different pages and each then causes `MainLayout.OnInitializedAsync()` to fire (makes sense) and in each case, a new instance of SessionData.

Why am I not getting the same instance for the life of the circuit/session?

How I am navigating as I test this:

1. Click an `<a href=...` in one of the pages to another page in the site.
2. Type in the full URL of another page in the site into the browser.
3. Call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(url);`
4. `DxMenuItem.NavigateUrl` which appears to be rendered as a `<a href=...`

None of those should reset - correct?

Comment: There's nothing in the code in your question that would cause the injected SessionData to be a new instance.  If it is then you are resetting the circuit/session in your navigation.

Comment: The first two are 1. the Server side render of the page,, 2. The setting up of the session from the client once the page is loaded.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I realize this may not be an answerable question, but how do I go about figuring out how/why I am resetting the circuit? My code is pretty vanilla. I'll update the question with how I'm navigating.

Comment: Create a [mre] in a new project. It will probably "just work". Then go looking for the differences.  Or post the mre here.

Comment: Travelling so a little slow in responding.  Check creation of services by adding a Guid Id and writing it to output/console in the constructor.  on your list 2 will as it resets the SPA just like an F5.  1,3 and 4 should not.